how to track bandwidth usage (up and down) and reconnections
I'm using mqtt.js in a Node.js project.  I would like to output occasional logging from the project that shows the bandwidth usage (i.e. number of bytes transmitted to, and received from, MQTT broker).
Is there a way to hook the existing socket connection in Node.js so that I can either read existing byte counters or count the bytes as they are sent/received?
It would also be nice to have a counter that shows how many times the client has automatically reconnected since initialization.  This would yield insight into the connection quality.
Any pointers appreciated on how to access or capture this data within the Node.js app.  In this case I'm not seeking ways to monitor bandwidth usage outside the Node.js app.  I realize these exist, but it seems the internal MQTT socket connection should be able to easily capture this information, providing a cross-platform solution with no external dependencies.
Also, this is a client-side request, not broker-side.
